# Laptop battery percentage indicator showing wrong value

Tags: laptop, battery

The battery indicator of my laptop is showing the wrong value. It constantly shows constant value, whether the battery is charging or if the laptop is in use and sometimes that constant value changes abruptly. I don't think my battery is bad. I have replaced the battery about one month ago. Also, I tried charging the battery for a long time, removed the power and ran the laptop, it worked fine about 3-4 hours before shutting due to running out of power, even though the indicator was constant and did not show a warning of low battery, and that is the battery life of my laptop. I have tried updating my battery driver, reinstalling the driver, but the problem persists. What should I do to fix it?
My OS is Windows 10 Home

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski but the battery is working fine. I have just replaced it and laptop runs for its battery life without problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you replaced the battery, did you use the Laptop Manufacturer's replacement battery?

If you used a third party replacement, it is quite possible (and normal) that the Laptop does not recognize the battery, and that is why you see the above symptoms.

Comment: yes, I purchased the battery from an official laptop service center

Comment: also, the indicator was working fine for half a month. now it is so bad that currently it is showing 0% battery and my laptop is still running.

Comment: Try updating / re-updating the Power Manager Driver again.  Check if there is a battery driver for your laptop. There is not a battery driver for my laptop / client laptops. See if possibly the battery can be exchanged

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can try:

> Right click Start to open Device Manager, under Battery choose the battery device, then Driver tab, then if available Roll Back the driver. If not available, choose Uninstall Driver, restart PC to reinstall.

([Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/battery-showing-wrong-percentage/0cee6f11-4314-4da2-867e-227b1a9f2ca9))

> If this was caused by Windows Updates then you can check which were installed at Settings>Update & Security>Windows Update under Installed Updates, then uninstall them from the link there. You can also use System Restore to get before the problem began.

(Same Source)

More links can be viewed at the source.